# What hook/filter can I use to add/edit/show/hide the title under (on hover) links on the table view?

Tags: filters, hooks

I'm not entirely sure the name given to these links, but the class is called "row-actions".

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use the `post_row_actions` filter https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_row_actions-2/

For example, to add a link, you could try something like:

```
function add_custom_link($actions, $page_object)
{
    $actions['custom_link'] = '<a href="http://www.example.com">My Custom Link</a>';

   return $actions;
}

add_filter('post_row_actions', 'add_custom_link', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks. I was arriving at the same conclusion by the time you posted. I am still however having one issue. When I log/dump $actions, I can see it's values, but when I do the same thing for $page_object I get nothing. Any ideas why the post object is not being passed?

Comment: Never mind. I had 10,1 instead of 10,2